# How do I join a hangout from my Calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-hangouts

I recently purchased an LG Tribute phone (Virgin Mobile carrier).  If I open up my Calendar, I can see a scheduled meeting in their that uses Google Hangouts.  Under "Location" there is a link that reads "Use Hangouts".  Unfortunately when I click on that link, I am taken into Google Maps.

What I would like is to be able to join the meeting using the Google Hangouts app on my phone.  How do I do that from the meeting invite on my calendar?

Thanks, - Dave